How to automate prompts during apt upgrades in bash?
I am running several Raspberry Pi 4 on Bookworm.  On these, I have a bash file as follows:
sudo apt -y update
read -t 600 -p "Pausing 10 minutes between Update and Upgrade"
sudo apt -y upgrade
read -t 600 -p "Pausing 10 minutes between Upgrade and AutoRemove"
sudo apt -y autoremove

Sometimes I get the below screen:

I also run this as a cron job (once a quarter) that calls the above script, but it fails when run via the cron.  How can I recognize that this GUI prompt is up and input the right answer?
Important Note: This doesn't happen always, so I want it to recognize when it happens and only then provide the correct input.

Check if the package has a non-GUI installer script.

The site you're looking for is either [unix.se] or [raspberrypi.se]. This is off-topic here, as it's not a programming question.

@DavidMakogon I'm sorry, can you elaborate on why it is not a programming question?  Are bash scripts not considered programming?  I need information on how to simulate stdin and stdout in this script.

Well, this is a tricky question: I think the close votes are because the preferable solution is not through a bash script adjustment, but rather through finding the right way to update packages in a non-interactive way. See for Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364742/how-to-do-apt-upgrade-with-noninteractive  There's almost certainly something like it for you, and people on those other sites will be able to help you figure it out.

If you really want to ask the question, how do I write a bash script to respond to these GUI prompts, you'll have better luck asking with a use case where that's a good idea in the first place. For package management, to be honest, it's almost certainly not a good idea because you would need to foresee any possible interactive question that might come up, and that can change as stuff gets released, which is why package managers offer a non-interactive variant that just won't ask any questions.

This question is not related to programming; it's a Linux/RPi question, specifically, and should be asked on the correct site. Also, you should not be editing a question to plead your case (I rolled this edit back, accordingly).

You're coming at this from the wrong direction. The tool you're running has a noninteractive mode so there's no reason to automate input to it at all; just run it in the mode where it doesn't start the TUI (which isn't a GUI) in the first place.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/556385/how-can-i-install-apt-packages-non-interactively is the first hit searching "apt noninteractive" and it fits with how I remember solving this problem myself in the past.

For the specific case of dpkg frontends such as apt, it's built to be able to disable interactive prompts altogether -- you don't need to automate the prompts, you can just turn them off.
Export the environment variable DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive while you run apt, and you'll get no more interactive prompts; if you need to assert specific settings, you can set them noninteractively with utilities from debconf-utils -- see its documentation.
Concretely:
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt -y update
read -t 600 -p "Pausing 10 minutes between Update and Upgrade"
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt -y upgrade
read -t 600 -p "Pausing 10 minutes between Upgrade and AutoRemove"
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt -y autoremove

